# Can you come up with your own service in BLE?

Tags: bluetooth, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have looked at the BLE specification, and found that the Bluetooth SIG has predefined a number of services, like heart rate. I am just wondering if it is possible for me to define a service myself? If can, is there any example available? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

yes, it's perfectly possible to define services yourself.

Services and characteristics are all identified by a UUID. For example the [BLE Services](http://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/services/Pages/ServicesHome.aspx) page lists all standardized services and the assigned UUIDs.

As you can see the Heart Rate services uses `0x180D`, which is a 16-bit short form reserved for standardized services only. The only requirement when defining your own service is that you use a 128-bit long form UUID.

Use `uuidgen` (available on Mac OS X) to generate a random (unique) UUID yourself:

```
uuidgen
# example result: 94B01578-5603-4D5A-8DFF-9365A1C4AC93
```

You can use this to publish and identify your own service. This can either be done on your own custom hardware, or through software on iOS (since you mention core-bluetooth).

Create your `CBMutableService`:

```
CBUUID *serviceUUID = [CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"94B01578-5603-4D5A-8DFF-9365A1C4AC93"];
CBMutableService *myService = [[CBMutableService alloc] initWithType:serviceUUID primary:YES];
// add some characteristics, also identified by your own custom UUIDs.
```

Finally see [addService:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBPeripheralManager_Class/Reference/CBPeripheralManager.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013015-CH1-SW3) &
[startAdvertising:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBPeripheralManager_Class/Reference/CBPeripheralManager.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013015-CH1-SW9) on `CBPeripheralManager` to start publishing your custom service.

After publishing this service using an iOS device you can scan for and connect to that service using another iOS device or a Mac, using the [CBCentralManager](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBCentralManager_Class/) class.

Answer (score 3):

Here's demo app with an example of setting up your own Bluetooth LE service on an iOS device: [SimpleShare](http://github.com/lauraskelton/simple-share)

You need to generate a UUID that's unique to your app's service. [This site](http://www.uuidgenerator.net) will generate one for you to use.